# How to use pfx/p12 cert?

Tags: kubernetes, ssl

I am trying to add our companies SSL cert to a kubernetes ingress. I have the following files

```
$ file ecdsa*
ecdsa.p12:          data
ecdsa.pfx:          data
ecdsa_pkey_p12.crt: ASCII text
```

I'm pretty sure I have the correct files, since I can see the expected expiration date

```
$ openssl x509 -in ecdsa_pkey_p12.crt -text -noout | grep "Not After"
            Not After : [REDACTED]
```

I need to get the certificate and key in base64 format, as described in the kubernetes documentation. How do I accomplish this?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

```
 kubectl create secret tls server --cert server.crt --key server-key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

`...I need to get the certificate and key in base64 format`

Try:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in ecdsa.pfx -nocerts -out ecdsa.key
openssl rsa -in ecdsa.key -out server.key
openssl pkcs12 -in ecdsa.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out server.crt

kubectl create secrete generic server --from-file=server.key --from-file=server.crt
```

Retrieve to see your key/crt in base64 `kubectl get secret server -o yaml`.